# How to write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer

Tags: django-rest-framework

Working with Django Rest Framework to create endpoints. I want to update Post with nested field "hashtag". This field is ManyToMany related with Post. If HashTag object is already exist, add it to Post object hashtag filed. If not, create new hashtag and add to Post object hashtag filed. If the request does not have a hashtag that was previously in the list, then delete it.

This is my **models**:

```
class HashTag(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(BaseModel):
    """A post posted by a user."""

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name="Created By",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="posts",
    )

    content = models.TextField()
    image = ProcessedImageField(
        upload_to=image_file_path,
        format="JPEG",
        options={"quality": 90},
        processors=[ResizeToFit(width=1200, height=1200)],
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    hashtag = models.ManyToManyField(HashTag, related_name="hashtags")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**Serializers:**

```
class HashTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HashTag
        fields = ("name",)

class PostDetailSerializer(PostSerializer):
    likes = serializers.StringRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    hashtag = HashTagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            "id",
            "user",
            "content",
            "image",
            "hashtag",
            "likes",
            "comments",
            "date_created",
            "date_updated",
        )
        read_only_fields = ("id", "user", "likes", "comments", "date_created", "date_updated",)
```

To update Post, I send next PUT request:

```
{
    "content": "Sunny weather today!",
    "image": null,
    "hashtag": [{"name": "sunnyday"}]
}
```

And I get this error:

```
The `.update()` method does not support writable nested fields by default.
Write an explicit `.update()` method for serializer `social_media.serializers.PostDetailSerializer`, or set `read_only=True` on nested serializer fields.
```

As I understand, I need to rewrite .update() method, so after searching same similar topics, I came up with this solution:

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
            hashtags_data = validated_data.pop("hashtag", [])
            Post.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
            hashtag_objs = [
                HashTag.objects.get_or_create(name=hashtag.get("name"))[0]
                for hashtag in hashtags_data
            ]

            instance.refresh_from_db()
            instance.hashtag.set(hashtag_objs)
            instance.save()

            return instance
```

But error still uppear. What do I do wrong?